# Suppose that f is a function and f(a)=b. What must be true about b for the use of the equal sign to be appropriate?

Tags: functions

It is my understanding that none of the statements below except for statement eight correctly use the equal sign. Is this true?

1.) f(a)=0/0

2.) f(a)=infinity/infinity

3.) f(a)=0/infinity

4.) f(a)=infinity/0

5.) f(a)=4/infinity.

6.) f(a)=infinity/4.

7.) f(a)=4/0.

8.) f(a)=infinity

Comment: It depends on the set of numbers you are operating on. Take a look, for example at the [Riemann sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere). All but 1) and 2) would be valid, there.

Comment: So, if b is in the extended complex plane, then statements 3-8 are valid. However, if b is in the standard complex plane, then only statement 8 is valid. Is this correct?

Comment: If $b$ is in the standard complex plane $\mathbb{C},$ then it cannot equal $\infty.$ If all you have is $\mathbb{C},$ you cannot even use $\infty$ in ordinary arithmetic operations. None of the above makes sense, then. You can only use $\infty$ as a symbol in limits, integrals etc.. $\infty$ is not a complex number.

Comment: Statement 3 is correct. Because $0/\infty =0$ this comes down to $f(a)=0$.